# "sort -h" not working correctly

Tags: command-line, command, sort

I tried sorting this file :

```
1000000911M
1G
2G
1.5G
100M
```

but using `sort -h file` I got :

```
100M
1000000911M
1G
1.5G
2G
```

Is there a problem with sort? If so how to avoid that without having to explicitly expand M,G ?

Comment: I think the problem is that 1000000911M is not a standard human friendly format (too many digits). How was it generated? Which linux distro and version? Which tool (command line or GUI)? - If you need high resolution, use basic integers instead of human friendly format.

Comment: @sudodus it wasn't generated, I was testing.

Comment: Well, Sotto Voce's answer is clear. If you have similar cases and need good sorting, you can use `numfmt`, and convert to basic integer numbers, try for example `numfmt --from=iec --to=none 10000001M`; (one line).

Comment: @sudodus thanks ! didn't know `numfmt`.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is documented in the man page for `sort`:

```
-h, --human-numeric-sort, --sort=human-numeric
         Sort by numerical value, but take into account the SI suffix, if present.
         Sort first by numeric sign (negative, zero, or positive); then by SI
         suffix (either empty, or `k' or `K', or one of `MGTPEZY', in that order);
         and finally by numeric value.  The SI suffix must immediately follow the
         number.  For example, '12345K' sorts before '1M', because M is "larger"
         than K.  This sort option is useful for sorting the output of a single
         invocation of 'df' command with -h or -H options (human-readable).
```

The relevant part is the fourth sentence:

```
For example, '12345K' sorts before '1M', because M is "larger" than K.
```

This is what you observed between your `1000000911M` line and the `1G` and `2G` lines that follow it.

In ordinary practice, the software that generates output with these kinds of suffixes will switch suffix rather than output so many significant digits.

Comment: An example like `numfmt --from=iec --to=iec <infile  | sort -h` might help.

Comment: @QuartzCristal Tip of the hat for the numfmt pointer.